# How to setup Provider for Strapi on Qovery?

Tags: strapi

I am getting this error on Google Sign in.
I did deploy on [Qovery](https://qovery.com) using Strapi.
How can I solve this issue?

> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed: http://0.0.0.0:1337/connect/google/callback

[image: Google showing error on sign-in]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I forgot to add `url` parameter on `server.js`*

Then:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
});
```

Now:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  url: env('URL', 'http://localhost:1337'),
});
```

Docs [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/users-permissions.html#setting-up-the-server-url).